# Resources folder value and status bar height

Tags: android, android-screen-support

How I must support two resolution

1) 1024px(Width) x 720px(Height) (mdpi) 
2) 1024px(Width) x 600px(Height) (mdpi)

I have different spacing in screen on different resolution.

I don't use qualifier values sw1024dp, I have different spacing.

I used [qualifier values w and h](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DesigningResources)  , but device not loader resources by folder 
values-w1024dp-**h600dp**, but correct loader value-w1024dp-**h575dp**. I think 25 dp - this is status bar height.

I try used theme Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen, but this is not work

Question:

Can I be sure that the status bar will always have a size 25dp?

And used folder value-w1024dp-**h575dp** - to resolution 1024pxX600px 
And used folder value-w1024dp-**h695dp** - to resolution 1024pxX720px

Comment: For the status bar height, all the design guidelines point to the height being constant for the foreseeable future http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

Comment: I saw this post, but here it is written that the icon should be 24x24 dp. About the size of the status bar, nothing is said.

Comment: OK after some digging you can see it here hardcoded in the platform: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/dimens.xml, search for status_bar_height